# Wine issue, quit working

Tags: wine

**Original Post**

I have been using Wine 1.6 for running several old Windows XP applications. Last night I tried to install a old win98 app and seem to have broken something.

I changed the "default" compatibility mode to "win98" in the Configure Wine window and exited out. The n tried to right click on the .exe file to use install wine application from the pop-up menu. Wine never launched the install.

When I tried to go back to "Configure Wine" it even failed to open and then to my shock I found that my other three windows XP applications that worked prior to this all failed to launch.

Doing some research I tried launching winecfg from the command line and it failed with an error with something about .idt failed to invoke.

So my question is how can I undo or fix my horrible mistake?
Is there a way to force the wine mode back to winXP?

Edit to add following

Per a suggestion I tried `winetricks winxp` but nothing happened, it just hung & I got the following:

```
gerald@gerald-Vostro-200:~$ winetricks winxp
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
```

When i run `winecfg`, I got:

```
gerald@gerald-Vostro-200:~$ winecfg

modify_ldt: Invalid argument

modify_ldt: Invalid argument

modify_ldt: Invalid argument

modify_ldt: Invalid argument

modify_ldt: Invalid argument

^C (I tried to cancle / close the hung up process)

err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7bcc7be0 "loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0024, blocked by 0009, retrying (60 sec)

^C

err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7bcc7be0 "loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0025, blocked by 0009, retrying (60 sec)

^C

err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7bcc7be0 "loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0026, blocked by 0009, retrying (60 sec)

err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000194 flags 0 addr 0x7bc367d1

err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7bcc7be0 "loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0024, blocked by 0009, retrying (60 sec)

^C

err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c000013a flags 0 addr 0xf77d3430

gerald@gerald-Vostro-200:~$
```

**UPDATE**

Looking around in the FAQ I found "10.6. Every app I try to start crashes" 
http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-7c6623cfe3fb6b542f4b0d97bea78ce682c7c16c

I was not able to recover my wine installation and had to remove it then reinstall.

All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

You still may still be able to change the Windows version using [`winetricks`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/winetricks):

```
winetricks winxp
```

This should set the Wine version back to Windows XP - it may not work if wine doesn't work.

---

The wine configuration (by default) is stored in the home directory in a hidden file called `~/.wine`. So another way to do this *(start again)*, would be backup the current wine configuration (you can restore it then if needed):

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.wineBACKUP
```

or remove it (permanently):

```
rm -r ~/.wine
```

---

A better thing to do in the future would be to run Wine with multiple config directories, each for a version of Windows (98, XP, etc). This is covered [in the Wine wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-f2f5f3bc795247f11962ea613a1f9e15657ad552), but basically if you install the WinXP programs normally in Wine, then run this:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine98" winecfg
```

and set up a second setup of Wine version for Windows 98, and then install it in that version:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine98" wine /path/to/program-that-needs-win98.exe
```

Both sets of applications should run happily, and if the Win98 one in `~/.wine98` mucks up, the WinXP in `~/.wine` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and future advice. I'm still having issues recovering my wine configuration.

Comment: Could add (i.e. [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/505483/edit) into) to your question what happens when your run `winecfg`? Also, you can back the current wine configuration by copying `.wine` to somewhere else.

Comment: Also, did the `winetricks` command work?